# Semantic classes approach results in huge inefficient CSS rules in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, less

I had a markup with no semantic classes, for instance all tables had classes

```
class="table table-compact"
```

etc. And I started to replace it with semantic classes. So for instance now I have:

```
class="users"
```

So I refactored the project and now my tables.css file is huge. For instance, the result of the following less:

```
.investment-mandate-table,
.outputs-table,
.globalvalidationlist-table,
.toplist-table,
.whitelist-table,
.address-book,
.admin-users-table,
.lac-cc-table,
.lac-members-table,
.aaf-instruments-table,
.search-result-aaf,
.search-result-short-list,
.search-result-instruments,
.whitelists-lac-table,
.whitelists-table,
.top-lists-table,
.local-packages-table,
.admin-cycles-table,
.lac-list-table,
.theme-list-table,
.short-list-table,
.cio-instruments-table,
.global-lead-offering-table {
    &:extend(.compact-table all);
    &:extend(.table-striped all);
}
```

contains about 1000 lines (each occurence of Bootstrap's tables CSS rule is extended...). Eg (small chunk):

```
.investment-mandate-table > thead > tr > th,
.investment-mandate-table > tbody > tr > th,
.investment-mandate-table > tfoot > tr > th,
.investment-mandate-table > thead > tr > td,
.investment-mandate-table > tbody > tr > td,
.investment-mandate-table > tfoot > tr > td,
/* many many others here ... */
.global-lead-offering-table > thead > tr > th,
.global-lead-offering-table > tbody > tr > th,
.global-lead-offering-table > tfoot > tr > th,
.global-lead-offering-table > thead > tr > td,
.global-lead-offering-table > tbody > tr > td,
.global-lead-offering-table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The size of the file does not bother me at all. But what bothers me is that this resulting CSS contains hundreds of CSS rules where the key selector is a HTML tag (in this case: td/th) - which is a performance disaster (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors) .

So basically do I have to compromise on CSS performance in order to have semantic CSS classes in this case?

Comment: Your result is actually expected. There's always  a compromise between number of classes in HTML element and number of classes in the CSS.

Comment: Besides, don't forget that Bootstrap is not a (Semantic) CSS *construction* framework, so no surprise the result is not that optimal (than it could be) when you try to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

### Reducing Classes in CSS Output

Depending on your exact situation, just looking at your code above, you may be able to reduce the output CSS significantly by using an attribute selector instead of many of your class names. You could do this if *all* of your `-table` classes are represented in this code (or at least *most* such that you override a few if need be). So this may work:

```
.address-book,
.search-result-aaf,
.search-result-short-list,
.search-result-instruments,
[class*=-table] {
    &:extend(.compact-table all);
    &:extend(.table-striped all);
}
```

It will reduce your output by 18 of the 19 `XXX-table` classes you had originally, multiplied of course by the number of places those extended to.

### Reducing HTML Selectors

The only "clean" way I can think of to do this is *not* very upgrade/maintenance friendly, and that is to go modify the Bootstrap file directly to eliminate the html tag names and put what you want to target those elements (which could have further repercussions in the useability of the code that would need to be carefully checked).

I would lean toward just living with it as the price paid for using Bootstrap for this particular operation, as basically [noted in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164963/semantic-classes-approach-results-in-huge-inefficient-css-rules-in-bootstrap#comment37304588_24164963).